# Incorrect output in Pascal's triangle program in C++

Tags: c++

I was creating a Pascal's triangle program in C++, but the output displayed is not as expected.

Output Expected

```
        1
      1   1
    1   2   1
  1   3   3   1
 1  4   6   4   1 
1 5   10  10  5   1
```

Output got

```
     1 
    1 1
   1 2 1
  1 3 3 1
 1 2 2 2 1 
1 6 6 6 6 1
```

Till i = 4, output displayed is correct, but after that I couldn't figure out how it goes wrong. Hers is the source code to get reviewed

```
int main()
{ int num, a[37680], t = 0, b = 2, l;
cout<<"Enter the number of rows: ";
cin>>num;
for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++)
{
    for (int j = 1; j <= (num - i); j++)
    {
        cout<<" ";
    }
    for (int k = 1; k <= i; k++)
    {
        l = k;
        if (k == 1 || k == i)
        {
            a[t] = 1;
            cout<<a[t]<<" ";
            t+=1;
        }
        else
        {
            a[t] = a[t - b] + a[t - b - 1]; 
            cout<<a[t]<<" ";
            t+=1;
            if ( l = (i - 1) )
            {
                b+=1;
            }
        }
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
return 0;}
```

Answer (score 2):

Equality checking in c++ is done using `==` and not `=`, so:

```
if(l=(i-1))
```

Should be:

```
 if(l==(i-1))
```